# How to count through a tags and apply +1rem padding to each one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to style some breadcrumbs programmatically, because I don't know how many breadcrumbs there will be (due to child categories being set up by the client, etc). I've tried a few ways to count through the a tags and do this, without much success. Basically I just want each a tag to have one more 1rem of left padding than the previous one. Here is my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < jQuery('.woocommerce-breadcrumb a').length; i++){
  jQuery('.woocommerce-breadcrumb a:nth-child(' + i + ')').css('padding', i + 'rem');
   }
```

Please excuse my bad coding as I'm just a novice with JavaScript/jQuery. And thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery inside of pure CSS, you don't have to use the `nth-child` selector to get each `a` tag, you could just loop through each `a` tag by using the jQuery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

Something like this should work:

```
$('.woocommerce-breadcrumb a').each(function(i, ele) {
  $(ele).css('padding-left', i + 'rem');
});
```

This will loop through every tag that matches `.woocommerce-breadcrumb a`, and then apply the relevant css. the `.each()` function let's you declare an index `i` in the function, so that lets us use incrementing `padding-left` for each element.

See this following code pen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLyOMj - for an example as well.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.each automatically passed an index so there is no reason to do the for loop.

```
$('.woocommerce-breadcrumb a').each(function(i) {
  $(this).css('padding', i + 'rem');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/79Lnpze8/

Comment: I wish I could pick two answers to be the answer, thanks so much!

Comment: Also, funny you should answer my question. I live in Worcester! Small world, huh? Wish there was a way to connect on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, based on your stated requirements:

```
// selects the <a> elements contained within an element with a
// class-name of 'woocommerce-breadcrumb',
// uses the css() method to update the 'padding-left' property
// with an anonymous function, in which the first argument
// here 'i' (the index of the current element in the set returned
// by the selector):
jQuery('.woocommerce-breadcrumb a').css('padding-left', function (i) {
    // returns a concatenated string, formed by the number of 1
    // added to the current index and finally with the units
    // added:
    return 1 + i + 'rem';
});
```

References:

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).